# Cannot add a new Controller?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Trying to create a new controller for the class Login:

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public string LoginId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
```

However, I keep getting an error saying that there is no identified Key which is weird as the naming convention and key declaration is being used.

[image]

Trying to lift a ban I assume is this question, dumb but I digress.

To fix this error, build the project BEFORE you try adding a controller.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How does EF have anything to do with adding a controller? How does the error even remotely have anything to do with what you're asking? Please could you add more specific details and how it is possible to recreate the problem you're having? This has got me very confused...

Comment: OK, so it's still no clearer what you're *actually* asking. To me, it seems like you're trying to scaffold a new controller with actions, and views - but because EF isn't liking one of your entities because you've probably not re-done a migration/build after something's changed? Your question is still no clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works.

However, each time I changed anything to the class, I had to rebuild the class and then you could create the controller.

Comment: Are you trying to say that all you needed to do was do a build on the project and it worked? This makes no grammatical sense...

Comment: Better? Hope it helps.

Comment: This is normal, the scaffolding works by using reflection which depends on the assembly generated after the build, without build, the scaffolding will not see any changes you made to the class